# Catch result of PowerShell's Restart-Service cmdlet

Tags: powershell

When running a script with:

```
Restart-Service ServiceName
```

How do I capture the result?  For example, if the service doesn't exist, I'll get a message like:

```
Restart-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'ServiceName'.
```

I've tried `try` and `catch` using `if ($error)` but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out the [ErrorAction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) parameter. If you just don't want an error you could try the following (check $? to see if it was successful).

```
Restart-Service ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

try catch does not catch all errors you see, only terminating errors. If you want to turn the error in a terminating error you could try the following.

```
try
{
    Restart-Service ServiceName -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    'Catched'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last error:

```
$error[0]
```